# Microsoft Sdk build error when compiling extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to compile this VS extension: https://github.com/madskristensen/HtmlTools2019

I'm getting this error:

[image]

I have installed the `Microsoft VisualStudio Sdk BuildTask`, but there's no 14.0 the lowest version is `14.0.156`:

[image]

I'm using VS22, I'm missing anything else?